There is a sequence of continuous, summable functions converging to a summable function but whose integral diverges
One more measure theory problem I cannot understand:
Definition:
A $\mu$-measurable function $f : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is $\mu$-summable if $f$ satisfies
$
\int_{\Omega} |f| \, d\mu < +\infty.
$
Problem: Disprove this: Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of continuous Lebesgue-summable functions on $[0,\infty)$ which converges to a Lebesgue-summable function $f$. Then
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{[0,\infty)} |f_n(x) - f(x)| \, d\mathcal{L}^1(x) = 0.
$$
Solution:
$$
f_n(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{n} - \frac{x}{n^2}, & \text{if } x \in (0, n), \\
0, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$
I don't understand why this disproves the above, given that
$f_n$ are summable and dominated by $\frac{1}{n}$ for each $n$, why is the limit of the integral not zero?

The obvious reason is that the pointwise limit is $f=0$, and $\int_{[0,\infty)}|f_n-f|\,dx=\frac{1}{2}$ for all $n$.
But as for why we can’t use the dominated convergence theorem, it’s because although $f_n$ is bounded by $\frac{2}{n}\cdot\chi_{(0,n)}\leq 2$, the constant function $2$ is not integrable on $[0,\infty)$. In fact, the observation above about the limit not being $0$ implies that there does not exist a dominating integrable function.
